# Accessing const NSString variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, constants

I try to define a const NSString in a class.

I have done the following:

**in .h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalDataModel : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *infoDictionary;

+ (id)sharedDataModel;

extern NSString * const WS_URL;

@end
```

**in .m:**

```
#import "GlobalDataModel.h"

@implementation GlobalDataModel

static GlobalDataModel *sharedInstance = nil;

NSString * const WS_URL = @"http://localhost:57435/IosService.asmx";


- (id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.infoDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }

    return self;
}

+ (id )sharedDataModel {
    if (nil != sharedInstance) {
        return sharedInstance;
    }
    static dispatch_once_t pred;        // Lock
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{             // This code is called at most once per app
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

usage:

```
#import "GlobalDataModel.h"

GlobalDataModel *model = [GlobalDataModel sharedDataModel];
```

Now, I can do

```
NSString *temp = model.infoDictionary[@"xxx"];
```

But not

```
NSString *temp = model.WS_URL
```

Because there is no WS_URL in the intellisense.

Comment: could you be more explicit on what you mean by *there*? can you post the code please?

Comment: @HepaKKes - I have modified my question with the while source. I hope, now its more clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've already replied to you, you cannot access that static variable in that way, although you could access to that `URL` via a readonly property associated to your singleton instance

Comment: the declaration `extern NSString * const WS_URL;` declares a global C symbol. declaring it inside an `@interface` does not alter its scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's why `NSString * const` is a different type from `NSString const *` so the compiler sees a redefinition of your `WS_URL`.

**EDIT**

If you think that you, having declared a constant in that way, you can do something like

```
#import "GlobalDataModel.h"
.
.
GlobalDataModel *model = [GlobalDataModel new];
model.WS_URL;
.
```

you're wrong, this is **not possible**: I suggest you instead to use a *readonly property* returning that constant.

So, try something like this

```
// GlobalDataModel.m
static NSString * const kURL = @"http://localhost:57435/IosService.asmx";
.
.
- (NSString *)WS_URL
{
    return [NSString stringWithString:kURL];
}

// GlobalDataModel.h
.
.
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *WS_URL;
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use module with constants like this:

Constants.h:

```
extern NSString * const WS_URL;
```

Constants.m

```
#import "Constants.h"   

NSString * const WS_URL = @"blabla";
```

in Module.m

```
#import "Constants.h"

...

NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"blabla=%@", WS_URL];
```